# How variadic templates work in the following cases?

Tags: c++, c++11

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d16c7e740a31a02

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> void P(T x) { std::cout << x; }
void foo(char a) {
    P(3);
    P(a);
}
template <typename... A>
void foo(int a, A... args) {
    foo(args...);
    P(a);
}
template <typename... A>
void foo(char a, A... args) {
    P(a);
    foo(args...);
}
int main()
{
    foo('1', '2', 48, '4', '5');
}

//1243548        My result (VS2015)
//12355248       correct result (clang, gcc)
```

How is the "correct" result being generated?

Comment: The linked compiler code is for C++14, and the question is marked C++11. Which is it?

Comment: Also the linked code does generate the correct code. Are you looking for an explanation of why? Perhaps you could also provide your failing code so we can tell you why it doesn't work?

Comment: @AndyG the listed my result is the output that I could figure out. VS2015 also outputs the same result as mine. Yes, I would like to know how the correct result is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that the `int` overload of `foo` has no idea about the `char` overload because it hasn't been seen yet, so calls at that level become recursive on itself:

```
template <typename... A>
void foo(int a, A... args) { /* only ever calls itself and above*/}
```

So a call to `foo(48, '4', '5')`

will recurse with additional calls to `foo(int a, A...)` where the *`chars` will be interpreted as `int`*!

So you'll get the initial `12` as expected, but then you'll solely print ASCII values for characters, so you'll get a value of `52` for `'4'`, and a value of `53` for `'5'`. Clang and gcc are correct; your version of Visual Studio is printing the wrong values. ([I was able to reproduce with VC 19.00.23506](http://rextester.com/LZCH48388))

Here's a call trace ([instrumented with some help from C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cabd5d3063165b1a)):

```
Called foo(char a, A... args) with 1,2,48,4,5
Called P(T) with 1
Called foo(char a, A... args) with 2,48,4,5
Called P(T) with 2
Called foo(int a, A... args) with 48,4,5
Called foo(int a, A... args) with 52,5
Called foo(char a) with 5
Called P(T) with 3
Called P(T) with 5
Called P(T) with 52
Called P(T) with 48
```

Now, if we move your code around so that we **forward declare** our templates (this is always a good practice), you'll get the behavior you desire:

```
template<typename T> 
void P(T x);

template <typename... A>
void foo(int a, A... args);

template <typename... A>
void foo(char a, A... args);

// actual definitions below...
```

Then you'll get your desired output. Here's a stack trace from that version ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09399a8a6aaea394)):

```
Called foo(char a, A... args) with 1,2,48,4,5
Called P(T) with 1
Called foo(char a, A... args) with 2,48,4,5
Called P(T) with 2
Called foo(int a, A... args) with 48,4,5
Called foo(char a, A... args) with 4,5
Called P(T) with 4
Called foo(char a) with 5
Called P(T) with 3
Called P(T) with 5
Called P(T) with 48
```